# Fractional Standing Wave Mode

Tags: waves, acoustics

This might seem like a silly question, but is it possible to have a decimal value for a standing wave mode, particularly for a rod with fixed ends? I understand from the photo below what it looks like when n = 1 or 2, but what happens if n is equal to 0.5, 1.5 or even 0.33? And what would the shape look like?

[image]

Comment: A standing wave needs to have the end points fixed. A non-integer value will not achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Wave reflections would not be in time with each other.  A standing wave would never form.  Until the oscillator nears a natural frequency of the system, the amplitude of any visible waves that form and then dissipate will have amplitudes similar to the oscillator that is the source of the waves.

When reflected signals are in time with the source signal, the reflected signals adds constructively to the source.  This reflection occurs at both ends, thus building up a very strong standing wave.  This happens when the wavelength of the wave fits the string appropriately.  When close to such a harmonic frequency, a small almost standing wave forms.  It strengthens as the frequency nears a harmonic frequency, the amplitude suddenly becomes very large.  This is similar to an oscillator approaching a resonance frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Take two homogeneous rods of different elasticity. Connect one end of each to a rigid wall and join the *other* the free ends to each other. This way any propagating wave in either direction would suffer a reflection at the "vibrating" junction due to the abrupt change of the wave impedance of the respective rod.